# Replace blank div card/panel with another one that is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and not sure I'm going about this the right way. What is happening is I'm grabbing data from pokemon api turning that data into cards that show up based on game selected. Data gets transferred via prop pokedex. Clicking on a card gets me the information for later storing/use.

Currently I can click the generated cards(from panelComp) and have only 1 show up. It does change based on what I click but does not replace the blank card. I know I will need a statement that stores the card in each div and wont let you go over 6.

What end goal and looking to do is to have 6 blank cards/panels up top as "empty"(grey boxes). I want to fill these with the selected pokemon cards/panels from the ones generated from PanelComp.

Later will be using the selected cards to make a filter based on pokemon types. I know I  will also need to add a click event to those cards so I can remove them back to blank. I have tried a few things to no avail any direction would be greatly appreciated as I just cant grasp this for some reason.

Code has placeholders via div emptyBox just so I can lay it out.

```
import Panel from './Panel';
import './PanelList.css';


const PanelList = ({ pokedex }) => {
    const [card, setCard] = useState(null);
    const [panelPick, setPanelPick] =useState(null);
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected]= useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPanelPick(panelComp[card]);
        setIsSelected(true);
    },[card]);

    const panelComp = pokedex.map((pokemon, i) => {
        return <Panel 
            onChange={num => setCard(num)} 
            panelId={i} 
            id={pokedex[i].id} 
            name={pokedex[i].name} 
            types={pokedex[i].types}
            />
    })

    const isItSelected = isSelected;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {isItSelected ? ( 
                        <div id='Block1'>{panelPick}</div> 
                         ) : ( 
                            <div className='emptyBox' id='Block1'></div> 
                             )}
                        </div>
                <div className='emptyBox' id='Block2'>{panelPick}</div>
                <div className='emptyBox' id='Block3'></div>
                <div className='emptyBox' id='Block4'></div>
                <div className='emptyBox' id='Block5'></div>
                <div className='emptyBox' id='Block6'></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {panelComp}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PanelList;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './Panel.css'

const Panel = ({id, name, types, panelId, onChange, onChildEvent }) => {

    const handleEvent = event => {
        onChange(panelId)
    };

    return (
        <div className="PNL" onClick={handleEvent}>
            <img className='pokeImg' alt='pokemon img' src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png`}/>
            <div className='Potext'>
                <h2>{name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substring(1)}</h2>
                <p>Id: {id}</p>
                <p>Type: {
                    types.map(type => 
                    type.type.name[0].toUpperCase() + type.type.name.substring(1))
                    .join(', ')
                }</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Panel;
```

This is my current code for the component and child in question. I can add more if needed from the parent. Not sure if I'm making this too difficult or not. I have been working at this for a few days and just don't know where to go with it. Really trying to learn as I go which I'm not sure if it helps.

Thank you

Comment: The problem is you aren't tracking an array of cards, but only a single one (card, setCard). There needs to be cardIndex and setCardIndex, and also a cardArray and setCardArray. When the user clicks to take a card, set cardArray[cardIndex] = card, and increment cardIndex. That's one way to do it anyway.

Comment: That does make sense. It gives me a direction for moving cards in and out and managing them. I think I got so hung up in learning hooks and events that I forgot a basic and arrays. I still have much to learn but I can see 1 way to a path at least now.